# Placing Point Attributes of adjacent polygons so that same point belongs to both polygons in table

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

When inserting a group of polygons, use extract vertices but when creating them, each point belongs to only one of the adjacent polygons and I need that in the attribute table the same point belongs to more than one adjacent polygon.

How is it done?

I am new using QGIS 3.18.

Answer (score 0):

1. Extract vertices (what you already did)
2. Menu Processing > Toolbox > Delete duplicate geometries
3. Create a new field with field calculator and this expression:

   `array_to_string (overlay_touches ('name_of_your_polygon_layer', $id))`

*Here, the expression is used to label each point with the `$id` of the polygons it belongs to:*

[image]